# Has anyone imported DrawingPanel.java to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

I'm working on a computer science graphics project that requires that I use drawingpanel.java.
I'm new to this and the explanations that I've seen that are even remotely close to this make no sense to me.

The code is presented in this form so I need to get it to work this way.

```
    import java.awt.*; // so I can use Graphics

    public class OutlineExample{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawingPanelpanel = new DrawingPanel(150, 70);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();     
        }
    }
```

I'm told that I have to "import" drawingpanel.java into my project somehow.

I've tried file -> import -> general -> filesystem but what happens makes no sense to me.
I also saw a post somewhere that said it might work to zip drawingpanel.java and rename it to .jar and then import it somehow.  I got nowhere with that.
Then I tried loading drawingpanel.java into its own project but then what?

Guess I need some step by step.....first push this button, select that file....push this button...type of instructions.  No leaps of logic.  I'm too dense at this point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Who gave you this code? You should not get your Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component since the Graphics object thus obtained will be short lived and will not work on subsequent repaints. As for "import" if your DrawingPanel class is in the same package as your current class, there's no need to specifically import anything. Also where is your code for DrawingPanel? If you have a java file, then you can just click on it and drag it into your project's package via Eclipse's package explorer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your DrawingPanel.java file readily available in a folder, you can simply drag it into Eclipse's package explorer by simply dragging and dropping. For instance:

[image]

As an aside, you should not get your Graphics object by calling getGraphics() on a component since the Graphics object thus obtained will be short lived and will not work on subsequent repaints. Instead your drawing should be within a JPanel's paintComponent method, which is perhaps what DrawingPanel is already doing.